# Are there small electric saws that can cut beef marrow bones?

Tags: equipment, cutting, bones, butchering

To get bone marrow out of whole beef bones, and for serving bone marrow in a bone piece on the plate nicely, you need to cut the bone into slices. It is a lot of work manually even for one cut, even more so doing several cuts on each bone for several bones.

I would also like to cut large fish like salmon into evenly sliced steaks. I can do it with a big knife, but they are uneven cuts, I would like perfectly even cuts like in frozen salmon slices from the supermarket.

There are electric butcher's bandsaws for this, but all I can find are huge machines, being in the form of a whole table. Do there exist any portable, semi-portable or at least in any form which can be placed on the counter-top? Or any other solution to achieve such cuts in cow leg marrow bones and big fish, without tiring myself out? On average would be doing several cuts a day.

Comment: One big consideration around using any sort of power tools is mess. A reciprocating saw in your kitchen would be a great way to make a big mess quickly, you're better off with the right manual saw.

Answer (score 2):

A manual butcher's saw will work fine on bone or frozen meat; they cut pretty quickly. (In particular, they will cut much more efficiently than a serrated knife or hacksaw, neither of which has appropriate teeth. **Never ever attempt to cut bone with a serrated knife.**) Butchers will often use a manual saw instead of a bandsaw for tricky angles or just to avoid having to transfer back and forth between a butchers block and the bandsaw.

The problem with using a small electric saw is that all of them are meant to be held two-handed with all body parts well away from the blade, meaning you'd have to clamp the meat in some way. Nevertheless, if you found a way to clamp things, an electric reciprocating saw with a fine-toothed blade would work fine.